How to Create Distribution Files and ISO After Enabling NTP Authentication in BusyBox for TinyCore?
I am working on a project where I need to enable NTP authentication in BusyBox's NTP daemon within TinyCore Linux. I have successfully enabled CONFIG_FEATURE_NTP_AUTH and compiled BusyBox. Now, I need to create distribution files and an ISO with these changes. Here is the script I use to compile and install BusyBox:
#!/bin/bash

# Install necessary tools
tce-load -wi compiletc sstrip

# Define variables for paths
NEW_BUSYBOX_DIR="$(pwd)/new_pkg"
COREPURE64_FILE="$(pwd)/corepure64.gz"
TEMP_CORE_WORK_DIR="$(pwd)/tmp_work_dir"

# Download and patch BusyBox
wget --no-check-certificate <URLs to various BusyBox sources and patches>
tar -xvjf busybox-1.36.0.tar.bz2
cd busybox-1.36.0
# Applying patches
patch -Np1 -i ../<patch_files>

# Update config and build BusyBox
cp ../busybox-1.36.0_config_nosuid .config
sed -i 's/# CONFIG_FEATURE_NTP_AUTH is not set/CONFIG_FEATURE_NTP_AUTH=y/' .config
make oldconfig
make CC="gcc -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe" CXX="g++ -flto -mtune=generic -Os -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti"

# Install the newly built BusyBox
mkdir -p $NEW_BUSYBOX_DIR
sudo make CONFIG_PREFIX=$NEW_BUSYBOX_DIR install

# Prepare and update the core image
cd ..
mkdir -p $TEMP_CORE_WORK_DIR
cd $TEMP_CORE_WORK_DIR
sudo zcat $COREPURE64_FILE | sudo cpio -idmv
sudo mv ./bin/busybox ./bin/busybox_old
sudo cp $NEW_BUSYBOX_DIR/bin/busybox ./bin/busybox
sudo find . | sudo cpio -o -H newc | sudo gzip -9 > new_corepure64.gz

echo "BusyBox update and core image preparation completed successfully."

How can I proceed to create distribution files and an ISO from this modified TinyCore setup? I am particularly interested in any specific steps or tools recommended for packaging these changes into a bootable ISO.

fyi this is off-topic, as it's not a programming question. Probably better to post this to [unix.se]
